# Python: "invert" fnmatch to match one file name?

Tags: python

This has to be simple; how do I exclude one file using `fnmatch` from a printed list generated by `os.listdir`?

This python script only lists the index.php file; I want to exclude index.php and list all other .php files. If I remove `if fnmatch.fnmatch(entry, 'index.php'):` I get a list of all files including index.php. Is it possible to "invert" `fnmatch`?

```
import os, fnmatch

listOfFiles = os.listdir('.')  
pattern = "*.php"  
for entry in listOfFiles:  

 if fnmatch.fnmatch(entry, 'index.php'):

    if fnmatch.fnmatch(entry, pattern):
            print (entry)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import os, fnmatch

listOfFiles = os.listdir('.')  
pattern = "*.php"  
for entry in listOfFiles:   
    if entry != "index.php" and fnmatch.fnmatch(entry, pattern):
            print(entry)
```

Comment: Nice. I didn't realize one could use an `if entry !=` construct.